# load multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to load data into a multidimensional array, but it doesn't seem to be coming out correctly. I have the stock id of the product, then under that I would like to load each of it's options names and values. All the variables have the correct data, it's just not building the array correctly Here is my code,

```
$completearray = array();
$x=0;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
 $x++;
 $completearray[$x] = $result['stock_id'];
 more code here
 $z=0
  foreach ($allattributes as $attribute)
  {
   more code here
   $z++
   $compeletearray[$x][$z]['option_name'] = $attribute['option_name'];
   $compeletearray[$x][$z]['option_value'] = $attribute['option_value'];
  }
```

I would like for the array to look like,

-stock_id

->option name

->option value

->option name

->option value

-stock_id

->option name

->option value

->option name

->option value

Comment: I think there is syntax error.  $compeletearray[x][z]['option_name'] should be  $compeletearray[$x][$z]['option_name']

Comment: yes, that was a typo, I updated my code. My actual code didn't have that mistake, still doesn't work with the missing $'s

Comment: can you please add sample output?

Comment: see there .. first you assigned $completearray[$x] = $result['stock_id']; as a int/string,
then again you are doing $compeletearray[$x][$z]['option_name'] = $attribute['option_name']; where $compeletearray[$x] should be an array. so its coming error

Comment: $completearray[$x] = array('ID'=>$result['stock_id']);  Fixed it, thank you Ameer